# Nothing was returned from render when using if statement and .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to return a component, which only should render if it's in a specific category. The category object that I fetch from the server has a list of product_ids. I pass the list of product_ids to the component and check if it's in the list, and if it does, return it.

However, when doing so, I get

`FormRow(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

```
// index.js (Every other function will be in this function as well)
export default function Index({ products, categories }) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();

    return (
        <div id="page-container">

            ...


                            <div id="products">
                { products && categories && <FormTabComponent/>  }
                            </div>
                    ...

        </div>
    );
}
```

So I'm trying to load `<FormTabComponent/>` and making sure both products and categories exist. Assuming this also means it checks if the objects aren't empty as well.

So FormTabComponent will render the following component, which seems like it renders fine.

```
  function FormTabComponent() {
    return(
      <SwipeableViews>
      <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>
          {categories.map((category, key) => (
            <Grid key={key} container spacing={1}>
              <FormRow productIds={category.product_ids}/>
            </Grid>
          ))} 
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <FormRow />
        </Grid>
      </TabContainer>
    </SwipeableViews>
    )
  }
```

The productIds that the  looks like this:

```
[ 'b2c66a6d', '9e303f69', 'cd210ce7', '436ce49c' ]
```

Here's FormRow, where the issue is at.

```
function FormRow({ productIds }) {
products.map((product, key) => {
  if (!_.isEmpty(productIds) && productIds.includes(product.id)) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Grid key={key} item xs={4}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Item
                id={product.id}
                title={product.title}
                description={product.description}
                currency={product.currency}
                price={product.price}
              />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
});
}
```

If I console.log productIds, I get the expected results, there's no undefined results.

Here's how I'm fetching the data:

```
Index.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
    const categories = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/categories');
    const products = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/products');

    return {
        categories: await categories.json(),
        products: await products.json()
    };
};
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Full error:

```
Invariant Violation: FormRow(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

Comment: You're only missing a `return` just before `products.map` in your `FormRow` component.

Comment: Hi @EmileBergeron as the first answer suggested, I added an else and return null, and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You added inside the `.map` callback, not where I said, which is your component that should return something, because `function FormRow({ productIds }) {` won't implicitly return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning null instead of not returning anything

in FormRow:

```
function FormRow({productIds}) {
  if(products && products.length > 0) {
    return products.map((product, key) => {
      if (!_.isEmpty(productIds) && productIds.includes(product.id)) {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Grid key={key} item xs={4}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <Item
                  id={product.id}
                  title={product.title}
                  description={product.description}
                  currency={product.currency}
                  price={product.price}
                />
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: Nope. I wish I could give more details but nothing was changed.

Comment: Products is coming from the parent function `export default function Index({ products, categories }) {`

Comment: Both of those functions are inside of Index(). When I console log them both, I still am able to get the data from it, but okay I'll try.

Comment: both of these are defined inside Index? I thought they were standalone function components

Comment: Both are defined inside of index.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work either :(

Comment: Exactly the same, I am seeing a 500 error though, even though i still do see products and such in console. here's the full code:

https://paste.vale.gg/uloracajuw.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197191/discussion-between-kinx-and-mo-ismat).

Comment: @kinx try it now, i updated the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Emile is right. In the second line of your FormRow snippet, add the word return to the front of the line.

The return you have in there is for the map, not for the render function.